# Kubernetes POD ran out of threads and became un-responsive and never recovered

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

We are running Spring Boot application on Rancher Kubernetes. The Kubernetes POD ran out of threads, but never breached the limits of CPU or memory (less than 80%). Since the CPU and memory limits are never breached, HPA never kicked in since they are set to CPU resource limits. The rancher POD became unresponsive and never recovered. Are there any resource settings on threads pools to avoid this failure in the future.

Comment: Please see this https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md The new metrics monitoring vision proposes an API that the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler can use to access arbitrary metrics.

Comment: so u mean, you were getting 500 errors at that time ?

Comment: What health check do you have setup for the app?

Comment: Your liveliness checks should fail as threads are max out. It should not serve your liveliness probs and will force bouncing the pod.

Answer (score 0):

If your application suffers from thread starvation before HPA kicks in, increase the number of web server threads by setting `server.tomcat.threads.max` (default is 200)

Alternatively, decrease resource allocation to your application in K8s manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Fritz. Let me try out with tinkering the server.tomcat.threads.max setting.